# Monitor Mode on broadcom 6.30.223.248 wl driver does not work

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I am trying to use broadcom card for sniffing wireless frames. With 6.30.223.248 wl driver, when I try to configure monitor mode using echo 1 > /proc/brcm_monitor0 , system Hangs.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 version. 
I have Broadcom BC94352 mini Pcie card.
I have tried on Kernel 3.2 / 3.11 / 3.15 . System hangs with kernels 3.11 and 3.15.
With 3.2 though prism0 interface is created for monitor mode. I could not set any channels and most of the frames are malformed.

Any help ?

Comment: Monitor mode is not supported by this chip.