# Intel AC7260 does not sniff LDPC packets

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I was searching for a WiFi 11ac sniffer which can work on Ubuntu.
I have tried Intel AC-7260 and Broadcom 4352, Both MiniPcie Form factor cards. 
With Intel I was able to get the latest firmware and able to sniff. But, it does not sniff if the packets are LDPC encoded other wise it sniffs 1 & 2 spatial stream data.
I used 3.15 kernel on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

With Broadcom, though I have taken latest "wl" driver from their web site, I could not set it monitor mode, which I have posted a query at [Monitor Mode on broadcom 6.30.223.248 wl driver does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502166/monitor-mode-on-broadcom-6-30-223-248-wl-driver-does-not-work)

Any one has tried anything else or using already please share your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Intel AC 7260 does not sniff LDPC packets is because it has H/W issues with LDPC. Intel claims it is fixed in next H/W AC7265.

In station Mode, though it connects by advertising LDPC support, there is a lot of packet loss, so disable LDPC to get it working.